# Detect exception in Eclipse console?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, exception

Hydi all,

Is there a way to detect exceptions in Eclipse console, or to extract list of exceptions when starting tomcat for example?

Comment: What do you mean with "detect"? There are breakpoints on exceptions if you want to pause execution on exception. Textual parsing? Extraction to a program/plugin? In the form of an eclipse plugin that plays a sound whenever there's an exception? Coloring it differently, sanitizing it from 300 to 30 lines?

Comment: yes, way to see if exception is in the log without searching it by scrolling the whole log, also count of exceptions in the log

Comment: To answer to myself, grep console plugin for eclipse/intellij can be used to highlight errors that occured in the log with error count if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Grep console plugin has capability to color specific phrases

https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/grep-console